# neovim nnoremap doesn't enter command mode after `gd`

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

Unfortunately `nnoremap ab gd:` doesn't work on my machine.

When I hit `ab`, the `gd:` remap selects the words under the cursor as `gd` (or `gD`) should do but it doesn't enter into command mode after as `:` usually does. If I type the sequence `gd:` or`gD:` directly in neovim, it works fine and enters into command mode after selecting the words under the cursor.

When I replace `gd` with `gg`, `nnoremap ab gg:` works fine. It moves to the beginning and enters command mode. Any ideas why `gg:` works while `gd:` doesn't?

My goal is to make a map such as:

```
nnoremap gR gD:%s/<C-R>///gc<left><left><left>
```

for global search and replace

I am using:

```
$ vim --version

NVIM v0.2.2
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.0.4
Compilation: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-    strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DDISABLE_LOG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wconversion -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -O2 -g -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/build/neovim-HJnLxJ/neovim-0.2.2/build/config -I/build/neovim-HJnLxJ/neovim-0.2.2/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/build/neovim-HJnLxJ/neovim-0.2.2/build/src/nvim/auto     -I/build/neovim-HJnLxJ/neovim-0.2.2/build/include
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +jemalloc +tui 
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

My full plugin free `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` looks like this (where `ab` doesn't work and `ba` does work):

```
set guicursor=
nnoremap ab gD:
nnoremap ba gg:
```

### Update

```
nnoremap ab gD:
```

`gD` means 'go to definition'. This fails when this command is executed at the defintion itself. It works only when:
**the selected word is not the first occurence**.

A simple workaround is to use a search with `*` instead of 'go to definition'
`nnoremap ab *:`. search and replace would then be:

```
nnoremap gR *:%s/<C-R>///gc<left><left><left>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going wrong with your map. It works for me (but I don't use Neovim).

However, rather than relying the side effects of `gd` or `*` (that they set the search register `"/`), you could instead insert the word into the search command more directly:

```
nnoremap gR :%s/\V\<<C-R><C-W>\>//gc<left><left><left>
```

*N.B. I'm using very-nomagic `\V` in the regular expression for consistency with your original command, `gd`.*

This utilises the command-line editing command <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>, which inserts the word currently under the cursor into the command-line. (See `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`)